# Chocolatey Question - Create a zip package of Powershell scripts?

Tags: chocolatey

I have some Powershell scripts with some associated files and no executable files.  It would be great if I could say run a command like Choco install MyStuff, and the installation would create a folder called C:\MyStuff and copy the Powershell scripts into the folder.  Pretty simple, but wondered if it's possible to do this with Choco.
Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

That's a very basic use case for a Chocolatey package. (basically a lot of the 'portable' Chocolatey packages work this way.)

I'd suggest you look into the help provided by the `choco new` command - you'll end up with a lot of information and hints on how to get started creating custom packages.

Just create a .zip / .7z file with the contents you want to deploy and create a Chocolatey package that utilizes the [`Install-ChocolateyZipPackage`](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-zip-package) helper function to extract that archive to a location of choice - such as C:/MyStuff.

See [nomacs.portable](https://chocolatey.org/packages/nomacs.portable) as example.

chocolateyInstall.ps1

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

if ((Get-OSArchitectureWidth 32) -or ($env:chocolateyForceX86 -eq 'true')) {
   throw "This package doesn't support 32bit architecture"
}

$fileName  = 'nomacs-portable-win.zip'
$toolsPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$zip_path = "$toolsPath\$fileName"
Get-ChildItem $toolsPath\* | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse

$packageArgs = @{
    PackageName  = 'nomacs.portable'
    FileFullPath = $zip_path
    Destination  = $toolsPath
}
Get-ChocolateyUnzip @packageArgs
Remove-Item $zip_path -ea 0
```

In this case the file 'nomacs-portable-win.zip' is extracted to the 'tools' folder - most likely 'C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/nomacs.portable/tools' - if you change 'Destination' in the script to 'C:/MyStuff' the extracted files will end up there.